# optim stuck on local minima when using negative log likelihood, but not least squares

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, optim

I'm trying to fit data in R with least squares and negative log likelihood.

However, I'm finding NLL won't find the global minimum that LS does find:

```
G <- function(pars, data) {
  pars['A'] * (1 - exp(-pars['age']*data$age))^pars['theta']
}

NLL = function(pars, data) {
  if (pars['age'] < 0){
    return(-Inf) 
  }
  if (pars['age'] > 1){
    return(-Inf) 
  }
  if (pars['theta'] > 10){
    return(-Inf) 
  }
  if (pars['sd'] < 0){
    return(-Inf) 
  }
  result = -sum(dnorm(x = data$agbd - G(pars, data), mean = 0, sd = pars['sd'], log = TRUE), na.rm = TRUE)
  ifelse(result == 0, -Inf, result)
}

nls <- function(pars, data) {
  result <- sum((G(pars, data) - data$agbd)^2)
  ifelse(result == 0, -Inf, result)
}


data_example <- data.frame(age = 1:32, agbd = c(19.0, 0.0, 5.0, 5.5, 14.0, 12.5, 15.0, 21.0, 28.0, 31.0, 26.0, 34.5, 51.5, 43.5, 52.5, 47.0, 42.5, 57.0, 48.0, 44.0, 52.5, 76.0, 59.0, 
79.0, 62.0, 77.5, 49.5, 58.5, 77.0, 55.5, 77.0, 89.5))

pars <- c(A = 100, age = 0.5, theta = 1.5)

o_nls <- optim(pars, nls, data=data_example, method = 'BFGS')
o_nls # o_nls$value = 2612.017

#####################
# note that
o_nls <- optim(pars, nls, data=data_example)
o_nls # o_nls$value = 2628.707
# so the default won't do as well as BFGS.
####################

pars <- c(A = 100, age = 0.5, theta = 1.5, sd = 0.5)
o_nll <- optim(pars, NLL, data=data_example)
o_nll
sum((data_example$agbd - G(o_nll$par, data_example))^2) #2638.79
```

I tried different data with the same functional form, and in some cases, for nonlinear least squares, the default optim method indeed did better than BFGS.

Any idea why NLL is not returning the global minimum in any case I try it? It shouldn't be outperformed by nls here.

Comment: I'm tempted to say "that's a feature, not a bug,"  but you haven't provided enough info to do an actual analysis.  what is your `G` function?   Which library's `optim` are you using?

Comment: very sorry, I'll edit the post!

G <- function(pars, data) {
  pars['A'] * (1 - exp(-pars['age']*data$age))^pars['theta']
}

and I'm using optim from the stats library!

Comment: Your nll has four parameters where as nls only has 3 parameters. Try fixing sd=1 in dnorm would yield similar values.

Comment: that's true, but shouldn't I be able to fit sd with NLL? Could it make that much of a difference?

Comment: Well, Ana,  why not try it out and see what happens?   Algos to find solutions, minima, etc.  can and do have all sorts of limitations on the domain over which they operate as desired.

Comment: I understand, and I had noticed that it would work well with fixed sd. I just thought that it meant there was some bug on my code, or on my understanding of the statistics behind it. I'll play with different sd values and see what happens. Thanks a lot!